# Case function with the count condition

Tags: sql, oracle, count

I'm using the case function to highlight the current scenario of my task running in my system, where the task status is Completed, Failed or Waiting.

I got the case function to use for Completed and Failed since it was just a one-line command. But for the Waiting state, I would like to build the condition with the count in the case function.

Currently, I'm using the syntax for waiting for the state

```
CASE WHEN     task_Status='Waiting' 
          and Count(Task_Status) > 30 
     THEN "More task are in Waiting State"
```

But the Count Function is giving me ERROR, Requesting the assistance on the same. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: It's simple. Take the count first in a cte or inline-view. Then apply your case.

Comment: Probably you need analytic window function: `count(*) over() `. Exact parameters depend on your needs

Answer (score 0):

It would have been nice if you posted sample data. As you didn't have a look at the following example based on Scott's schema. Instead of your `status` column, I'm counting clerks in every department.

```
SQL> select deptno, ename, job from emp order by deptno, job;

    DEPTNO ENAME      JOB
---------- ---------- ---------
        10 MILLER     CLERK            --> 1 clerk in department 10
        10 CLARK      MANAGER
        10 KING       PRESIDENT
        20 SCOTT      ANALYST
        20 FORD       ANALYST
        20 ADAMS      CLERK            --> 2 clerks in  
        20 SMITH      CLERK            --> department 20
        20 JONES      MANAGER
        30 JAMES      CLERK            --> 1 clerk in department 30
        30 BLAKE      MANAGER
        30 MARTIN     SALESMAN
        30 WARD       SALESMAN
        30 ALLEN      SALESMAN
        30 TURNER     SALESMAN

14 rows selected.

SQL>
```

This is what you're trying to do now:

```
SQL> select deptno,
  2         case when job = 'CLERK' and count(*) > 1 then
  3                  'More than a single clerk in department'
  4              else
  5                  'Only one clerk in department'
  6         end status
  7  from emp
  8  group by deptno;
       case when job = 'CLERK' and count(*) > 1 then
                 *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression


SQL>
```

If we include the `job` column, error goes away, but - result isn't what we expected:

```
SQL> select deptno,
  2         case when job = 'CLERK' and count(*) > 1 then
  3                  'More than a single clerk in department'
  4              else
  5                  'Only one clerk in department'
  6         end status
  7  from emp
  8  group by deptno, job
  9  order by deptno;

    DEPTNO STATUS
---------- --------------------------------------
        10 Only one clerk in department
        10 Only one clerk in department
        10 Only one clerk in department
        20 Only one clerk in department
        20 More than a single clerk in department
        20 Only one clerk in department
        30 Only one clerk in department
        30 Only one clerk in department
        30 Only one clerk in department

9 rows selected.

SQL>
```

What to do? Don't `count` - `sum`!

```
SQL> select
  2    deptno,
  3    case when sum(case when job = 'CLERK' then 1 else 0 end) > 1 then
  4              'More than a single clerk in department'
  5         else
  6              'Only one clerk in department'
  7         end status
  8  from emp
  9  group by deptno
 10  order by deptno;

    DEPTNO STATUS
---------- --------------------------------------
        10 Only one clerk in department
        20 More than a single clerk in department
        30 Only one clerk in department

SQL>
```

---

In your case, that would be

```
case when sum(case when task_status = 'Waiting' then 1 else 0 end) > 30 then
          'More tasks are in Waiting State'
end
```

Note that strings should be enclosed into **single**, not double quotes.